# Salesforce Communities Groups Email Settings

Tags: chatter, community, chatter-groups

I have a client who recently started using communities and is loving it so far.  The question i have is about groups, if we create a group and add members to it are they automatically getting emails about posts or do they have to login and turn that on?

I know they can select never, but the default option seems to be "blank" so im not sure what thats translating to?

Also when we first invite a member to a group is there some kind of welcome messsage?  (i know they can get a welcome message when they are first added the community at all.

**UPDATE**: as far as i can tell in winter 14 the defaults have changed and new group members are defaulted to a "weekly digest"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Communities users are not automatically opted into any group email notifications. Blank is the default and it translates email off. Each user would need to select their preference within that group. There is not a group welcome email functionality at this time either. The group welcome email is a good suggestion, you should post it on the IdeaExchange.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have a custom visualforce page to edit email settings, would like to offer it as part of signup

Comment: I don't believe so but I'm not 100% sure, it's not something I've tried. According to the docs, CollaborationGroupMember, which holds the individual's setting inherits from the user's default email settings on create. Default email settings don't exist in Communities, and the preference is not updatable.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you could setup the group default AND the create the group welcome by adding an After Insert trigger on the NetworkMemberGroup table.

Comment: Are you sure triggers on NetworkMemberGroup are possible ?

Comment: You're right Samuel - that object doesn't allow a trigger.